Moving floating windows around with keyboard shortcuts
I'm currently using a Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon 6.2.9 installation that is a couple days old and I want to use some features I had on a previous tiling window manager with XFCE. In particular, I want to move floating windows around with shortcuts. In order to do that I made this brief Bash script:
#!/bin/sh
win_id=`xdotool getactivewindow`

u=`xwininfo -id $win_id | grep 'Absolute upper-left X' | cut -c27-35`
v=`xwininfo -id $win_id | grep 'Absolute upper-left Y' | cut -c27-35`

(( u+=150, v=$v-86 ))

xdotool getactivewindow windowmove $u $v

It intends to move a floating window 150 px along the X-axis only (the 86 pixels that I subtract from the Y-axis are the window's upper decoration which is considered by xwininfo but not by windowmove.
When I execute it in the terminal, it works fine, but when I try to bind it to some keyboard shortcut (e.g., Super + G), the selected window moves only +86 px on the Y-axis.
Can anyone replicate this? What could be the cause of this inconsistency? I already have verified that other kind of key-bind scripts executes well (like open other programs).
